# What is the matrix corresponding it a linear transformation of a polynomial?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, polynomials

Given the linear map $T(f(x)) = f(2x+1)$ where $f(x)$ is a polynomial of degree $3$, what is the matrix corresponding to $T$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The phrase "the matrix" is incorrect here. How one associates a matrix to a linear map $T:V\to W$ depends on choices of bases for $V$ and $W$.

The rule is as follows.

Let $T:V\to W$ be a linear map and let 
\begin{align*}
\alpha &= \{v_1,\dotsc,v_n\} &
\beta  &= \{w_1,\dotsc,w_m\}
\end{align*}
be bases for $V$ and $W$ respectively. This means there are unique scalars $\lambda_{ij}$ for $1\leq i\leq m$ and $1\leq j\leq n$ such that
$$
\begin{array}{ccccccccc}
T(v_1) & =      & \color{red}{\lambda_{11}}w_1 & + & \color{red}{\lambda_{21}}w_2 & + &\dotsb &+ & \color{red}{\lambda_{m1}}w_m \\
T(v_2) & =      & \color{blue}{\lambda_{12}}w_1 & + & \color{blue}{\lambda_{22}}w_2 & + &\dotsb &+ & \color{blue}{\lambda_{m2}}w_m \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots          &\vdots &\vdots       &\vdots &\ddots&\vdots&\vdots \\
T(v_n) & =      & \color{green}{\lambda_{1n}}w_1 & + & \color{green}{\lambda_{2n}}w_2 & + &\dotsb &+ & \color{green}{\lambda_{mn}}w_m \\
\end{array}
$$
The **matrix of $T$ relative to the bases $\alpha$ and $\beta$** is defined as
$$
[T]_\alpha^\beta=
\begin{bmatrix}
\color{red}{\lambda_{11}} & \color{blue}{\lambda_{12}} & \dotsc & \color{green}{\lambda_{1n}} \\
\color{red}{\lambda_{21}} & \color{blue}{\lambda_{22}} & \dotsc & \color{green}{\lambda_{2n}} \\
\vdots       & \vdots       & \ddots & \vdots \\
\color{red}{\lambda_{m1}} & \color{blue}{\lambda_{m2}} & \dotsc & \color{green}{\lambda_{mn}}
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Note that this is an $m\times n$ matrix.

Now, in your case we have a linear map $T:P_3\to P_3$ where $P_3$ is the vector space of all polynomials of degree at most three. The map is defined by $T(f(x))=f(2x+1)$. Since you haven't specified bases, we will use 
$$
\alpha=\beta=\{f_1,f_2,f_3,f_4\}
$$
where
\begin{align*}
f_1(x) &= 1 & f_2(x) &= x & f_3(x) &=x^2 & f_4(x) =x^3
\end{align*}
Following the algorithm, we have
\begin{align*}
T(f_1) &= 1  \\
T(f_2) &= 2x+1 \\
T(f_3) &= (2x+1)^2=4x^2+4x+1 \\
T(f_4) &= (2x+1)^3=8x^3+12x^2+6x+1
\end{align*}
That is,
$$
\begin{array}{ccccccccc}
T(f_1) & = & 1\cdot f_1 & + & 0\cdot f_2 & + & 0\cdot f_3 & + & 0\cdot f_4 \\
T(f_2) & = & 1\cdot f_1 & + & 2\cdot f_2 & + & 0\cdot f_3 & + & 0\cdot f_4 \\
T(f_3) & = & 1\cdot f_1 & + & 4\cdot f_2 & + & 4\cdot f_3 & + & 0\cdot f_4 \\
T(f_4) & = & 1\cdot f_1 & + & 6\cdot f_2 & + & 12\cdot f_3 & + & 8\cdot f_4 
\end{array}
$$
Hence 
$$
[T]_\alpha^\alpha=
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
0 & 2 & 4 & 6\\
0 & 0 & 4 & 12\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 8
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Answer (score 1):

A basis for the space of polynomials is $\{1,x,x^2,x^3\}$ Now, for a finite dimensional space $V$ with a basis $\{e_1,\cdots e_k\}$ if $T$ is a linear operator then, for any vector $u=\sum a_i e_i$, $T(u)=T(\sum a_ie_i)=\sum a_i T(e_i)$ by linearity. So, the matrix representation of $T$ will be the matrix with its columns as $\{T(e_i)\}$. In this case the columns will be $$T(1)=3\equiv[3\quad 0\quad 0\quad 0]^T,\\
T(x)=2x+1\equiv[1\quad 2\quad 0\quad 0]^T,\\
T(x^2)=(2x+1)^2\equiv[1\quad 4\quad 4\quad 0]^T,\\
T(x^3)=(2x+1)^3\equiv[1\quad 6\quad 12\quad 8]^T$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: take the basis $\{1,x,x^2,x^3\}$. If
$$f(x)=a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+a_3x^3$$
then
$$f(2x+1)=a_0+a_1(2x+1)+\cdots=(\cdots)+(\cdots)x+(\cdots)x^2+(\cdots)x^3.$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** So, I assume that you want $T$ to act on the space of degree $3$ polynomials. In that case, you have a natural basis consisting of the polynomials $1$, $x$, $x^2$, and $x^3$, and you could evaluate $T$ on each of them.